# Angular - Get values from key value

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I get data from URL and I have this data in result :

```
array: 2[
    1 => "LA"
    2 => "NY"
 ]
```

I want to show only value in List . Here is my code :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('/getCities').
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.cities = data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // log error
            });
        });
```

Is it the best way to show them?

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in cities">
  <li>  {{ value }} </td>
</ul>
```

**EDITED :** I edit my html to :

```
                            <ul ng-repeat="city in cities">
                                <li>  {{ city }} </li>
                            </ul>
```

Actually , I give this error :
*angular.min.js:117 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]*

Comment: Does it work? If so, then why ask the question?

Comment: Also, please read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Comment: What exactly is the data structure returned? What you have at the top of your question isn't anything understandable by JavaScript.

Comment: Are you getting a json response?

Comment: @Phil No , It doesn't

Answer (score 1):

This is an `array`. You don't need key value notations for repeatation. Just write

```
<ul ng-repeat="city in cities">
  <li>  {{ city }} </td>
</ul>
```

and Thats all.

Comment: How do you know it's an array? Seems to be more akin to a map with keys "1" and "2", ie `{"1":"LA","2":"NY"}`. Until OP confirms, we're all just guessing

Comment: Well it is shown above in square bracket notation and it has `array` written before it. either of this if it were an object the above code should work fine for the repeat in the markup.

Comment: I am also guessing. :)

Comment: I get this error : angular.min.js:117 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]

Comment: This error occur when duplicates are being used in repeats. You can use `<ul ng-repeat="city in cities track by $index">` to avoid it. But it is not recommended until you want to allow duplicates.